# Two Jquery are not working in Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I m using fisheye dockmenu in my Master page and its working fine. When I add the slider jquery in one of the content page, then fisheye dockmenu is not working in all the pages. But the slider jquery is working in the content page. Please help me out what is the problem.

FishEye DockMenu in Master Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery_dockmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/interface.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('.dock').Fisheye
        ({
            maxWidth: 50,
            items: 'a',
            itemsText: 'span',
            container: '.dock-container',
            itemWidth: 40,
            proximity: 90,
            valign: 'top',
            halign: 'center'
        })
    });
</script>
```

Slider Jquery in Master Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
```

Slider Coding in Content Page:

```
<div style="margin:30px auto;max-width:800px;">

<!-- Insert to your webpage where you want to display the slider -->
<div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:16px auto 56px;">
    <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t1.png" alt="t1" /></li>
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t2.png" alt="t2" /></li>
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t3.png" alt="t3" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t1-tn.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t2-tn.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="Slider/images/t3-tn.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End of body section HTML codes -->
```

Comment: is `jquery_dockmenu.js` including it's own version of jquery?

Comment: you aren't including the jquery file twice are you (or only including the jquery.js file above the slider but not the dockmenu - it will need to be before both)

Comment: @Pete: Sorry I m bit confused. Can you please explain me...

Comment: where you have `<script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>` above your slider, do you have something similar above your dockmenu?  If so remove the one that is lower down the page

Comment: Thank you @Pete - Just I replaced dockmenu.js after to jquery.js. Its working nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be referencing your `jquery_dockmenu.js` before `jquery.js`.  What I like to do is place everything at the bottom of the Master Page right before the closing body tag:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Slider/sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery_dockmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/interface.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.dock').Fisheye
            ({
                maxWidth: 50,
                items: 'a',
                itemsText: 'span',
                container: '.dock-container',
                itemWidth: 40,
                proximity: 90,
                valign: 'top',
                halign: 'center'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*This also improves the loading speed of your page.*

Comment: Thank you Scott! Just I replaced dockmenu.js after to jquery.js. Its working nice...